# Java Swing Range Slider U.I

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, jslider

I needed a slider with two knobs on it (representing a range) and I found this nifty one [here](http://blog.limewire.org/?p=340).  However, they created their own U.I. which extends Java's [BasicSliderUI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSliderUI.html).  They override the paint method to draw their own knobs.  I would like to use the default knobs based on the current *look and feel*.  I tried calling *BasicSliderUI*'s [paintThumb](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSliderUI.html#paintThumb(java.awt.Graphics)) method, but this gives me a generic looking knob which doesn't seem to be tied to the current look and feel.  As far as I can tell, [JSlider](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) gets its U.I. from [MultiSliderUI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/multi/MultiSliderUI.html).  How can I create a U.I which changes like [JSlider](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html)'s, but draws two knobs instead of one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, now feel free to post the links.  I'm too lazy to do it myself.

Comment: P.S. sorry about that restriction.  It is there to prevent link spammers.

Answer (score 5):

[SwingX](http://www.swinglabs.org) provides [JXMultiThumbSlider](http://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMultiThumbSlider.html) which may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the current look and feel from the `javax.swing.UIManager` and calling `getUI(new JSlider())` on it. This should return the current UI used for the `JSlider`, which should be castable to `JSliderUI`.

Unfortunately `JSliderUI` doesn't have a `paintThumb(Graphics g)` method, but the `BasicSliderUI` does, and at least on Windows XP and Windows Vista the system look and feel is a subclass of `BasicSliderUI`, so is the Metal look and feel.

So once you have the `JSliderUI` see if it is an instance of `BasicSliderUI`, if so you can cast it to `BasicSliderUI` and use the `paintThumb(Graphics g)` on it, otherwise default to the way you are doing it already. I don't know if this actually works, but it would be my first attempt if I needed it.

I don't have Linux or Mac to check the source if their `JSliderUI`s are derived from `BasicSliderUI` as well, but if you do then check out the java source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RangeSlider class from 
    [Jide Commons Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)

This is opensource.