# Is there any range slider to select a time period?

Tags: java, swing

For my application I need a range slider for a time period. That is I have a starting date and a end date. Now I want to create a Range Slider that allows the user to select a range between the starting date and the end date.

Before coding it myself, I wanted to check if there is already something like this available, but using Google i only found range slider for numbers.

Can anybody recommend a time range slider?

Comment: Yes (I'll add that tag, thanks)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140303/java-swing-range-slider-u-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806781/using-jslider-to-create-a-date-chooser

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're not specifically after a single slider.

[Date Slider](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Dateslider.htm)